# Rewrite posts url as they're all children of a page

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

If my theme's user wants to set a static page as home, i want to make all posts url as they're children of the chosen blog index page.
By example, suppose permalink is similar to;

`http://www.example.com/example-post`

or even with dates, and the chosen post index is named `Blog`, i want the permalink to be:

`http://www.example.com/blog/example-post`

I tried to use the rewrite api this way (accounting the url structure without pretty permalinks)

```
function rewrite_rules () {
    if (get_option('show_on_front') == 'page') {
        add_rewrite_rule('blog/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$)', 'index.php?p=$matches[1]', 'top');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'pagination_rewrite_rules');
```

but this got no effect: visiting `blog/example-post` sticks on `blog`. How can i achieve this goal? Thank you.

**EDIT**

I found out that visiting url appending page id instead of slug, like `blog/page-id`, it works. But i want to use slugs! Working on it but still waiting for a pro solution

Answer (score 0):

Oh well, i just remembered i can have this result without even programming. And if the theme is not for me i can advice how to do in docs. It was simple: Settings/Permalink/Custom Structure. I hope i'll be helpful for someone.